# How do I get my DIV elements to wrap only if there is not enough screen real estate to display them?

Tags: css, inline

I would like to keep the following elements on the same line (horizontal plane), provided there is enough horizontal real estate to do so …

```css
#profileContainer {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.profileField {
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id=“profileContainer”>
<div class="profileField">
    Birthday<br> 
    <div class="select"><div class="select-styled">Select Month</div><ul class="select-options"><li rel="">Select Month</li><li rel="1">January</li><li rel="2">February</li>…<li rel="12">December</li></ul></div>
<div class="select"><div class="select-styled">Select Day</div><ul class="select-options"><li rel="">Select Day</li><li rel="1">1</li><li rel="2">2</li><li rel="3">3</li><li rel="4">4</li>…<li rel="28">28</li><li rel="29">29</li><li rel="30">30</li><li rel="31">31</li></ul></div>
<div class="select"><div class="select-styled">Select Year</div><ul class="select-options"><li rel="">Select Year</li><li rel="1900">1900</li><li rel="1901">1901</li><li rel="1902">1902</li><li rel="1903">1903</li><li rel="1904">1904</li>…<li rel="2019">2019</li><li rel="2020">2020</li><li rel="2021">2021</li></ul></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, if you look at my JSFiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/3nwpv8ch/, you’ll notice that even when you compress the screen horizontally so that there’s not enough room for the elements, they do not start to wrap, and instead you simply cannot see them.  How can I get the elements to wrap only if there is not enough horizontal screen real estate available?  If there is enough, I would want the elements to continue to remain on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, where you simply remove `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` from the `profileField` rule

*Note: I also temporary removed the `translate` so one easily can see how it behaves*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/3nwpv8ch/6/)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#profileContainer {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.profileField {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.selectMenu {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
}

.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 42px;
}

.select-styled.active {
  background-color: #737373;
}

.select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 11px 12px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: darken(gray, 5);
}
```

```html
<div id="profileContainer">

  <div class="profileField">
    Birthday
    <br>
    <div class="select">
      <div class="select-styled">Select Month</div>
      <ul class="select-options">
        <li rel="">Select Month</li>
        <li rel="1">January</li>
        <li rel="2">February</li>
        <li rel="3">March</li>
        <li rel="4">April</li>
        <li rel="5">May</li>
        <li rel="6">June</li>
        <li rel="7">July</li>
        <li rel="8">August</li>
        <li rel="9">September</li>
        <li rel="10">October</li>
        <li rel="11">November</li>
        <li rel="12">December</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="select">
      <div class="select-styled">Select Day</div>
      <ul class="select-options">
        <li rel="">Select Day</li>
        <li rel="1">1</li>
        <li rel="2">2</li>
        <li rel="3">3</li>
        <li rel="4">4</li>
        <li rel="5">5</li>
        <li rel="6">6</li>
        <li rel="7">7</li>
        <li rel="8">8</li>
        <li rel="9">9</li>
        <li rel="10">10</li>
        <li rel="11">11</li>
        <li rel="12">12</li>
        <li rel="13">13</li>
        <li rel="14">14</li>
        <li rel="15">15</li>
        <li rel="16">16</li>
        <li rel="17">17</li>
        <li rel="18">18</li>
        <li rel="19">19</li>
        <li rel="20">20</li>
        <li rel="21">21</li>
        <li rel="22">22</li>
        <li rel="23">23</li>
        <li rel="24">24</li>
        <li rel="25">25</li>
        <li rel="26">26</li>
        <li rel="27">27</li>
        <li rel="28">28</li>
        <li rel="29">29</li>
        <li rel="30">30</li>
        <li rel="31">31</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="select">
      <div class="select-styled">Select Year</div>
      <ul class="select-options">
        <li rel="">Select Year</li>
        <li rel="1900">1900</li>
        <li rel="1901">1901</li>
        <li rel="1902">1902</li>
        <li rel="1903">1903</li>
        <li rel="1904">1904</li>
        <li rel="1905">1905</li>
        <li rel="1906">1906</li>
        <li rel="1907">1907</li>
        <li rel="1908">1908</li>
        <li rel="1909">1909</li>
        <li rel="1910">1910</li>
        <li rel="1911">1911</li>
        <li rel="1912">1912</li>
        <li rel="1913">1913</li>
        <li rel="1914">1914</li>
        <li rel="1915">1915</li>
        <li rel="1916">1916</li>
        <li rel="1917">1917</li>
        <li rel="1918">1918</li>
        <li rel="1919">1919</li>
        <li rel="1920">1920</li>
        <li rel="1921">1921</li>
        <li rel="1922">1922</li>
        <li rel="1923">1923</li>
        <li rel="1924">1924</li>
        <li rel="1925">1925</li>
        <li rel="1926">1926</li>
        <li rel="1927">1927</li>
        <li rel="1928">1928</li>
        <li rel="1929">1929</li>
        <li rel="1930">1930</li>
        <li rel="1931">1931</li>
        <li rel="1932">1932</li>
        <li rel="1933">1933</li>
        <li rel="1934">1934</li>
        <li rel="1935">1935</li>
        <li rel="1936">1936</li>
        <li rel="1937">1937</li>
        <li rel="1938">1938</li>
        <li rel="1939">1939</li>
        <li rel="1940">1940</li>
        <li rel="1941">1941</li>
        <li rel="1942">1942</li>
        <li rel="1943">1943</li>
        <li rel="1944">1944</li>
        <li rel="1945">1945</li>
        <li rel="1946">1946</li>
        <li rel="1947">1947</li>
        <li rel="1948">1948</li>
        <li rel="1949">1949</li>
        <li rel="1950">1950</li>
        <li rel="1951">1951</li>
        <li rel="1952">1952</li>
        <li rel="1953">1953</li>
        <li rel="1954">1954</li>
        <li rel="1955">1955</li>
        <li rel="1956">1956</li>
        <li rel="1957">1957</li>
        <li rel="1958">1958</li>
        <li rel="1959">1959</li>
        <li rel="1960">1960</li>
        <li rel="1961">1961</li>
        <li rel="1962">1962</li>
        <li rel="1963">1963</li>
        <li rel="1964">1964</li>
        <li rel="1965">1965</li>
        <li rel="1966">1966</li>
        <li rel="1967">1967</li>
        <li rel="1968">1968</li>
        <li rel="1969">1969</li>
        <li rel="1970">1970</li>
        <li rel="1971">1971</li>
        <li rel="1972">1972</li>
        <li rel="1973">1973</li>
        <li rel="1974">1974</li>
        <li rel="1975">1975</li>
        <li rel="1976">1976</li>
        <li rel="1977">1977</li>
        <li rel="1978">1978</li>
        <li rel="1979">1979</li>
        <li rel="1980">1980</li>
        <li rel="1981">1981</li>
        <li rel="1982">1982</li>
        <li rel="1983">1983</li>
        <li rel="1984">1984</li>
        <li rel="1985">1985</li>
        <li rel="1986">1986</li>
        <li rel="1987">1987</li>
        <li rel="1988">1988</li>
        <li rel="1989">1989</li>
        <li rel="1990">1990</li>
        <li rel="1991">1991</li>
        <li rel="1992">1992</li>
        <li rel="1993">1993</li>
        <li rel="1994">1994</li>
        <li rel="1995">1995</li>
        <li rel="1996">1996</li>
        <li rel="1997">1997</li>
        <li rel="1998">1998</li>
        <li rel="1999">1999</li>
        <li rel="2000">2000</li>
        <li rel="2001">2001</li>
        <li rel="2002">2002</li>
        <li rel="2003">2003</li>
        <li rel="2004">2004</li>
        <li rel="2005">2005</li>
        <li rel="2006">2006</li>
        <li rel="2007">2007</li>
        <li rel="2008">2008</li>
        <li rel="2009">2009</li>
        <li rel="2010">2010</li>
        <li rel="2011">2011</li>
        <li rel="2012">2012</li>
        <li rel="2013">2013</li>
        <li rel="2014">2014</li>
        <li rel="2015">2015</li>
        <li rel="2016">2016</li>
        <li rel="2017">2017</li>
        <li rel="2018">2018</li>
        <li rel="2019">2019</li>
        <li rel="2020">2020</li>
        <li rel="2021">2021</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="profileField" style="background-color:green;">
    Line 2 - should be on a new line
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update based on comment

If you want the `container` to grow when there is space, you could do like this, where you set `width: 100%` and a `max-width: 720px` (the sum of the `select` items) on the `#profileContainer`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/3nwpv8ch/8/)

Comment: Hi, I clicked on your "Updated Fiddle" link but there was no CSS in there.  Anyway, I tried applying your suggestion to my Fiddle (removing the inline-block and nowrap elements) and keeping the translate attributes in there, but now things are displaying on different lines even though there is enough room for all of them -- https://jsfiddle.net/3nwpv8ch/5/ .

Comment: @Mike Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/3nwpv8ch/6/ ... will update link in my answer

Comment: I see it now.  The problem is when I add the CSS to center things, then the DIV elements no longer stay on the same horizontal plane.  I added the lines to your Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/3nwpv8ch/7/

Comment: @Mike What's the problem? .. when there is space the jump up .. or you mean they should push the parent if it has space on its left/right?

Comment: @Mike Like this you mean?  https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/3nwpv8ch/8/ ... updated/added my answer with this too

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is `flex-wrap: wrap;`. It allows you to wrap the divs when there is not enough room.

Comment: So would I put this in my "#profileContainer" style or my ".profileField" style?

Comment: I think that you need to put the divs in a list and add it to the list. Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3nwpv8ch/2/